# Filter new lines between two files to new file

Tags: batch-file, text, compare

I'm trying to compare two text files and save the results in a new file. It should display only lines that are new and ignore sort orders. I just want to see what is new and no line changes. To reach this I tried several ways inside a batch file you can see below.
First I use uniq and sort to change the order of both files like:

```
D:/filetype/sort.exe -b D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp3_1.txt -oD:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp4.txt
```

After that I tried to compare both files to a new one.

1) via comm

```
D:/filetype/comm.exe --nocheck-order -2 -3 d:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt d:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/all.txt > D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp5.txt
```

a terrible solution, doesn't work correctly. If there is something different in the order it gives out a lot of false results. As an example if I save the result to the archive and compare it again with itself it is displaying new lines.

2) Via diff

```
D:/filetype/diff.exe --new-line-format="" --unchanged-line-format="" d:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt d:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/all.txt > D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp5.txt
```

Same as .comm, if I compare the archived file with itself it will display new lines.

3) Grep, SED and Diff

```
D:/filetype/diff.exe -U $(wc -l < (D:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt) (D:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt D:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/all.txt | D:/filetype/grep.exe '^-' | D:/filetype/sed.exe 's/^-//g' > D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp5.txt
```

Wasn't able to get this running on a Windows Batch, and can't figure out why the error message "Wrong syntax for file or folder name" appears. Any ideas would be great.

Some futher information
- I'm using coreutils inside Windows
- Could use a .py script, batch, php and corutils
- I add the result to the archive

Here is an example file:
http://pastebin.com/raw/tNGSu2W6

First: I compare it with an empty txt file (all.txt), in the last step I merge it into all.txt (as archive) and normaly with the next run he shouldn't find any difference.

```
copy /b D:\filetype\listfile\archive\*.txt D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_tmp_all.txt
D:/filetype/uniq.exe D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_tmp_all.txt > D:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/tmp_all2.txt
D:/filetype/sort.exe -b D:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/tmp_all2.txt -oD:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/all.txt
```

To not confuse anyone this is the whole thing (it's a bit spartan).
http://pastebin.com/T68sqpET

*Update 1*
Changed the pastbin code, there was a typo on the part with diff.exe "`< filename < filename > output`" will trow error messages on windows. Also the numbers were not the fault of diff. I used "uniq.exe -c" and needed to remove the -c.

Comment: Can you [edit] and add your two test files?

Comment: Done :) i hope pastebin is okay.

Comment: I see some unbalanced `()` parentheses in the last command line. Moreover, you need to [Escape](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) all `cmd` poisonous characters to supply them properly to `diff.exe`: escape `<` as `^<` and to `grep.exe`: escape ˙^˙ as `^^`.

Comment: Solution 2) seems to work fine here if using cygwin `diff`

Comment: @JosefZ , i will try your suggestion and give you feedback. DavidPostill, i think it might have something to do with uniq,  i found duplicated lines in the archive file after a second run, i currently need to check why the lines in the archive are not uniqe.

Comment: @JosefZ I changed it now to `D:/filetype/diff.exe -U $(wc -l ^< (D:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt) (D:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt D:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/all.txt) | D:/filetype/grep.exe '^^-' | D:/filetype/sed.exe 's/^-//g') > D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp5.txt` but i guess there is something more wrong, now i got the message that he couldn't found drive D:

Comment: Please **do not** post code snippets in comments. Follow the [tour]: _Use [edit]s to … clarify the meaning of a post_. Sorry, I'm not experienced in `unix`/`cygwin` commands.

Comment: Maybe escape `|` pipe operator as well? And _**he** couldn't found drive D:_ - what's the **he**? a `cygwin` or `cmd`?

Comment: I'm using cmd for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i figured out why comm didn't work correctly. The Command

```
D:/filetype/comm.exe --nocheck-order -2 -3 d:/filetype/listfile/listfile_clean_tmp4.txt d:/filetype/listfile/archive/tmp/all.txt > D:\filetype\listfile\listfile_clean_tmp5.txt
```

Doesn't need `--no-check-order`, but that is not all. The main reason why it was failing in comparing was, that i used uniq or merger in mein Tool Chain and do not sort it always strict again after parts of the textfile have been edited. It is highly important that files that will be compared with comm are always sorted in the right order. Here is an example with linux sort from coreutils

```
D:/filetype/core/sort.exe -b D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\bruteforce.txt -o D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\bruteforce2.txt
D:/filetype/core/uniq.exe  D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\bruteforce2.txt > D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\bruteforce3.txt
D:/filetype/core/sort.exe -b D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\bruteforce3.txt -o D:\filetype\listfile\archive\tmp\bruteforce4.txt
```

**Notice:** sort will make no trouble if you sort the same file without copying it to a other location (other than uniq which will react badly to doing so). I personal prefer temp files, but they are not necessary for sort.

```
D:/filetype/core/sort.exe -b D:/filetype/listfile/listfile.txt -o D:/filetype/listfile/listfile.txt
```

Or with simple words.. "**Change it > Sort it**" if you would like to compare it.